# Django sort form fields from two models

Tags: django, django-forms

I have extended the Django user model with some extra fields

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('telephone', 'email_address', 'date_of_birth')
        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def response_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            date_of_birth = profile_form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
            user = profile_form.cleaned_data['user']

            context = {
                'user': user,
                'date_of_birth': date_of_birth
                }
            template = loader.get_template('thank_you.html')

            return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'response_form.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

When the template is loaded it places the user fields above the profile fields.

[image]

How can I place the *User* dropbox above the *First name* field?

Comment: Since those are fields from different forms, you have no other way than to display your fields one by one in your template. So don't do `{{ user_form.as_p }}` or whatever you use to display the entire form at once, but display the labels, fields and errors for each field in your template explicitly. Note: you should set a `prefix` on at least one of your forms, to avoid name conflicts between fields (like the email).

Comment: sort of "filedsets -> fileds" is the answer you're looking for. which one comes first is on top of the rest

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks. Back to basics then

Comment: You just need to use `{{ user_form.first_name }}`,  `{{ user_form.first_name.tag_for_label }}` and `{{ user_form.first_name.errors }}` etc...

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mixing the order of the fields on two different forms, there's no way to do that whilst still using `{{ my_form.as_p }}` or similar methods to render your forms in your template.

You have to render your form fields individually, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Note that when having multiple forms in one view, it's always wiser to add a `prefix` to your forms, in order to ensure that field names are unique in your HTML page. In your case, you might have a conflict with the email field.

Also when successfully completing the form, it's standard practice to **redirect** (302 REDIRECT) your user to the 'thank you' view rather than **render** the 'thank you' template (200 OK). This is because a page refresh (F5 or cmd-R) will otherwise resubmit the data.